# How to put c++ string into char array

Tags: c++, string

If I have something like

char name[10];

and I want to put the string s into name, where s = "joe"

how would I do that?

Also, can I make a function that takes strings as inputs, but treats those as char arrays?

Comment: @Phenom: you have been asking a lot of string questions.  Please read up on the `std::string` interface.  This is a good place to start: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/  Or this: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html

Answer (score 7):

```
strcpy (&name, s.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` has a `c_str` member that converts it to `const char*`. To copy from one char array to another use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy()` will generally get the job done. `strncpy()` is better, if available.

Comment: One caveat on strncpy(): it won't null-terminate if the source string is longer than the length argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C++ string, you can call its `c_str()` method to get a `char *`, suitable for using with `strcpy()`, defined in `<cstring>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::memcpy(name, str.c_str(), str.size() + 1);
```